# Dynamic List Looping Performance

Tags: c#, linq

I am cleaning the old code and found following Dynamic Loop.

```
foreach (var obj in listValues.Where(x => x.Valid == false))
{
}
```

I have a question that, the performance will be increase of following code as compare to above loop?

```
var myList = listValues.Where(x => x.Valid == false);
foreach (var obj in myList)
{
}
```

Comment: I doubt if it will be any difference in performance: the optimizer is smart enough to add / remove local variable (`myList`)

Comment: It is exactly the same. Why would there be a difference? (Remark: If the type of `.Valid` is a plain `bool` (and not a nullable, `bool?`, or something), then most people prefer writing `(x => !x.Valid)` instead, but this is for stylistic reasons, not because of performance.) PS! This is not considered "dynamic". The `Where` method gives a so-called iterator that functions lazily (deferred execution).

Answer (score 2):

Moving the `listValues.Where(x => x.Valid == false)` to the variable will not increase the performance the loop. `foreach` is actually compiled into `while` loop with result of `listValues.Where(x => x.Valid == false).GetEnumerator()` stored in separate variable. Something [like next](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEAsBuWDkQHQBkBLAOwEdMYA3AQwCdEAbQgZwBcA1ahgVwFNnEAXkTFeAd0RE2AHhKsAfAG8AvhQBmAe1q9qAYwAWiABQ16GgEYArRCUYsOXPs1wB1fb21GAHkPmJWtHwAlEGwirDKQA):

```
    IEnumerator<int> enumerator = listValues.Where(...).GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            int current = enumerator.Current;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (enumerator != null)
        {
            enumerator.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

So no additional enumerations should happen (if that is your concern).